# In the HTML output generated by rst2html, sections at all levels are all with class "section", can I config it?

Tags: restructuredtext, rst2html.py

In the HTML output generated by rst2html, sections at all levels are all with class "section". Can I config it?

Thus, if I want apply my own CSS to the HTML output, I just can not use different styles for top-level section and sub-section, because they have the same class name?

How to solve this problem if I want to apply different styles to sections at different level?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this problem by writing my own rst writer class Inheriting docutils.writers.html4css1.Writer, and in its constructor, assign it a instance of class HTMLTranslator Inheriting docutils.writers.html4css1.HTMLTranslator to its translator_class attribute.

Specifically， in my `HTMLTranslator` class, the method `visit_section` is overridden::

```
def visit_section(self, node):
    self.section_level += 1
    self.body.append(
        self.starttag(node, 'div', CLASS='section section%d' % self.section_level))
```

Thus, section at level 2 will get a class `section section2`.

Answer (score 0):

You might give a try to `class` directive. This is an HTML-specific directive and it allows setting an arbitrary class to the elements that follow it. The full description is here: http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#class

Here is an example:

```
Regular header
==============

.. class:: myclass

Section with a class myclass
****************************

Regular paragraph
```

Comment: Thank you！I have solved this problem by writing my own rst writer class Inheriting `docutils.writers.html4css1.Writer`, and in its constructor, assign it a instance of class `HTMLTranslator` Inheriting `docutils.writers.html4css1.HTMLTranslator` to its `translator_class` attribute.